# How to repeat function until conditions will not compiled

Tags: c++

I got code:

```
void Grown()
          {
    if(!hero.getMoving()
    {
        SendAttack(int 110000001, int 1)
    }
         }
```

How to repeat function ( if(!hero.getMoving() ) until conditions will not compile?
I don't want repeat all void Grown(), only if(!hero.getMoving()

Comment: For one thing, you're missing a right paren at the end of the `if` line. Not sure exactly what you're trying to ask though, so it's hard to say more.

Answer (score 2):

just put a loop thus

```
void Grown()
      {
while(!hero.getMoving())
{
    SendAttack(int 110000001, int 1)
}
     }
```

Comment: That's some pretty strange indentation there...

Answer (score 0):

Change if to while:

```
void Grown()
{
  while(!hero.getMoving())
  {
    SendAttack(int 110000001, int 1)
  }
}
```

This loop will halt when your hero has moved.